# Display thumbnail image in iframe

Tags: java, html, iframe, embed, facebook-iframe

I am fairly new in this. I have the following `iframe`

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<%=video1[1]%>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What I am trying to do is have it play `video1[1]`, but show the image that is in `video1[2]`.

I tried doing is:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" href="<%=video1[2]%>" src="<%=video1[1]%>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but that doesn't work.

Is there a simple way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no attribute as 'href' in iFrame tag.
See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

You could maybe build an iFrame which acts as a target for a link:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<%=video1[1]%>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen name="iframe_video1"></iframe>

<a href="<%=video1[2]%>" target="iframe_video1"><img src="<...>"/></a>
```

BTW: Pay attention that in an iFrame's source attribute, there has to be a document (i.e. web page) referenced, no media/video directly.
You could use YouTube links e.g. to be embedded.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!