# How to get frame as picture from specific time using YouTube API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

For example I want to get StackOwerflow logo as picture from youtube video.

> From this youtube address: https://youtu.be/QwS1r1mc888?t=2
>
> At this time: 00:02

I can take current video time, video data etc.

```
player= document.getElementById("movie_player");

player.getCurrentTime();
// ...
player.getVideoData();
```

How can I get video frame from specific time?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -3):

It is not possible to add a thumbnail image on iFrame.

You can use the iFrame of youtube as a target using . And then you can use a  inside the  tag

Check this answer:

[Display thumbnail image in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743403/display-thumbnail-image-in-iframe)

Comment: I don't want to get thumbnail image. I want to get exact frame in video then convert it to picture format.

Comment: @MuhammedOzdogan according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25144716/4092887), it seems is not possible to do what you want. My suggestion *(I haven't tried, honestly)* is check how to get a screenshot "maybe using the approach used by the app [Snipping Tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipping_Tool)" and *(once the video loaded)*, execute the screeenshot functionality.